# Easiest way to access ZIO test generators from Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, read-eval-print-loop, zio

I'm just starting out using ZIO in Scala. I've written some Scalacheck-style tests using ZIO's `Gen` type, and they appear to work, but I'd like to manually test the generators in the REPL to ensure that they're actually producing the data I expect them to.

The problem: everything in ZIO is wrapped in the ZIO monad, and I need to pass the right data into this monad to unwrap it and view the results. And there's no documentation explaining how to do this in the REPL.

I think I understand how to do it for a basic program with no environment dependencies: call `zio.Runtime.default.unsafeRun`. But the `Gen` objects expect an environment of type `Random with Sized`, and I don't know how to produce an instance of this.

**Given a `Gen[Random with Sized, T]`, what is the quickest way to execute it on the REPL and get a `List[T]` of generated values?**

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a partial solution, but I'm not completely satisfied with it.

For just printing some samples from a `Gen` on the REPL, this works:

```scala
zio.Runtime.default.unsafeRun(
  yourGenerator
    .runCollectN(50)
    .provideLayer(zio.random.Random.live +!+ zio.test.Sized.live(100))
) foreach println
```

But I don't think this is how it's *supposed* to be done. `provideLayer` doesn't typecheck unless I provide *both* `Random` and `Sized`, even though `Random` should be part of `zio.Runtime.default`. I think there's something about `ZLayer` that I still don't understand.